# How do I get the Server Ping on BungeeCord using Java or Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, minecraft, bungeecord

I am trying to get the ping of a server. How do I do this in Kotlin or Java

My current code:

Kotlin:

```
class Events: Listener {
    @EventHandler
    fun joinEvent(event: PostLoginEvent) {
        var plugin = Main.getInstance()
        var server = plugin.proxy.getServerInfo("pserver")
    }
}
```

Java:

```
public class Events implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    void postLogin ( PostLoginEvent event){
        Main plugin = Main.getInstance();
        ServerInfo server = plugin.getProxy().getServerInfo("pserver");
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: could you be more precise ? your goal isn't clear to me ( technos used for example)

Comment: You can use `((CraftPlayer) target).getHandle().ping`, but i dont think it will work inside `PostLoginEvent`, try making a command for it

Comment: @Ofek the given code is for spigot/paper, not for bungeecord.

Comment: @Clafter does my answer reply to your question ? Does it fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get ping of a server. The ping is the latency between 2 things (here, the player and the server). So, everytime, such as the server don't change, we are getting the ping thanks to the player instance (it will manage it's own  ping).

I don't know how to do it on Kotlin, but on Java (Bungeecord) it's :

```
proxiedPlayer.getPing()
```

So, you have to use it like that :

```
@EventHandler
public void postLogin(PostLoginEvent event){
    ProxiedPlayer proxiedPlayer = event.getPlayer();
    int ping = proxiedPlayer.getPing(); // this is what you want
}
```